# change upload folder and putting the location of the image in the api - sails.js

Tags: sails.js

I have a client-side application register form that send data to my sails.js based server.
other then the basic data that's being send, i also have an image upload that uploads the image to ./tmp/uploads

here is my server side code(in the controller):

```
upload: function  (req, res) {
   req.file('avatar').upload({ dirName: 'uploads' }, function (err, uploadedFiles){
      if (err) return res.send(500, err);
      res.view({
        items: uploadedFiles
      });
   });
}
```

1) how do i change the folder that the files goes to? i obiously dont want the files be saved in .tmp folder

2)how do i insert the image location to the data api that has just being created? and speaking of image location, how do i access the image file? i usualy expected something like this localhost:1337/.tmp/uploads/file.jpg would work.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to put an absolute path in the prop 'dirname', for example:

```
var PATH = '/var/www/app/uploads';
req.file('avatar').upload({ dirname: PATH }, function (err, uploadedFiles){
```

Or you can use a relative path to the controller:

```
var PATH = __dirname + '/../uploads';
req.file('avatar').upload({ dirname: PATH }, function (err, uploadedFiles){
```

2) You have access to every model in your controllers, suppose that you have an `Image` model, you could save the location this way:

```
Image.update({id:1},{location: PATH + '/' + uploadedFiles[0].filename})
```

Comment: ok so i managed to put the file in assets/images.now i got another problem. the image is saved with some random name, how can i change it to the original file name?